# Getting this warning while running ng serve for angular 12 - Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Workstation\fe\assets\css\core.css

Tags: css, angular, angular12

[image: warning message]

My angular was 7, but recently I upgraded it to 12.0.5. The ng build goes fine and ng serve is also executing without any error but always getting the above warnings. Also, I am trying to open these css files in browser like localhost:4200/assets/core.css I can see that it's loading [css files loading in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2K72.png) but not sure why this is not applying in the project hence resulting into undesirable styles and design.

my index.html looks like

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" >
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aNUYGqSUL9wG/vP7+cWZ5QOM4gsQou3sBfWRr/8S3R1Lv0rysEmnwsRKMbhiQX/O"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/liwid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styleguide.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom.css">
```

my angular.json

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        ]
```

Comment: why dont u import those file in `style.css` file? as: `import "yourLocation.css";`

Comment: @לבנימלכה I tried this solution and after this I don't see the warning message but I can also see the css files are not applied and same distortion with the design and style is there.

Comment: check if the url is correct(may change when move.. try `./asset/..`)

Comment: @לבנימלכה `@import "assets/css/core.css";
@import "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css";
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "assets/css/liwid.css";
@import "assets/css/styleguide.css";
@import "assets/css/custom.css";` I tried this.

Comment: in F12 do you see any error or do you see the file load?

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes there are errors I can see on the console                                          `main.js:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(t)[o -> o -> o]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for o!
    at ps.get (main.js:1)
    at vs.get (main.js:1)
    at vs.get (main.js:1)
    at vs.get (main.js:1)
    at ml.get (main.js:1)
    at Object.get (main.js:1)
    at qe (main.js:1)
    at Ye (main.js:1)
    at Object.Ks (main.js:1)
    at ke.t.ɵfac [as factory] (main.js:1)` also the assets/css directory is not loaded in the browser.

Comment: so you have to find the correct url

Comment: @לבנימלכה I am unable to understand what else url is required.

Comment: I suggest you apply the updates incrementally. Like from `v7` to `v8` first, then from `v8` to `v9` and so on. Then you'll be able to figure out what went wrong.